# Using custom topics and listeners for MQTT on IoT Hub

Tags: python, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

We are trying to use Azure IoT Hub as an MQTT Broker for a project. Following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support).
We understand that Azure IOT Hub is not a full replacement for a MQTT Broker, however, we noticed that we can only send messages to topic - ""devices/" + device_id + "/messages/events/". Also , when we try to connect multiple listeners to same MQTT Endpoint, they keep connecting and disconnecting until we keep the max listeners to "1".

Is there any configuration that we need to change so the IOT Hub is able to publish to a custom topic and have more than a single listener?

Thanks

Comment: The Azure IoT Hub is not a generic MQTT Broker, you should consider for your solution to use the Azure IoT Edge MQTT broker to publish and subscribe messages, see more details in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-publish-subscribe?view=iotedge-2020-11

Comment: Or use an established MQTT broker that you install in a VM, or in Kubernetes - https://www.hivemq.com/best-practices-for-operating-hivemq-and-mqtt-on-kubernetes/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we need to understand the Azure IoT Edge runtime and its architecture as we have few things to check such as IoT Edge Hub, IoT Edge Agents (Here we will be able to understand runtime based on status codes.)

Refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-runtime?view=iotedge-2020-11) for more info

Azure IoT Edge MQTT broker is used to publish and subscribe messages.

Have a look on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-publish-subscribe?view=iotedge-2020-11) where we’ll be able to understand how to connect to this broker, publish and subscribe to messages